# ChartJS custom legend doughnut separate legend from chart area

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, chart.js, legend

I'm attempting to separate the `Legend` from my `Chart` in a **ChartJS** chart.
When using the '*default*' legend, there is no way to control the chart area size and it will get smaller the more items I have in my legend...

If it is possible to expand the `Legend` without changing the `Chart Area` size, I would love to hear about anyone thats done this :)

The other option which I'm trying, is to create a custom `Legend` and insert it as innerHTML, and hide the default legend.

I've tried solutions using the `legendCallback` such as:

[example 1](https://www.py4u.net/discuss/358487)

[example 2](https://dev.to/giselamd/creating-a-custom-chart-js-legend-style-50i5)

[example 3](https://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/b5hdn9gw/)

but all of them do no work for me... not sure why, I've done it exactly as they specify.

I'm thinking it might be the version of `ChartJS` (I'm using the latest) or some other data issue that is preventing the legend from showing.

**my code:**

```
var chart1 = document.getElementById('displayVals').getContext('2d');
var mychart1 = new Chart(chart1, {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: {
        labels: namelist,
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Doughnut Chart :)',
            data: valuelist,
            backgroundColor: GraphColors,
            borderWidth: 0
        }]
    },
    options: {
        layout: {
            padding: chartPadding
        },
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,

        legend: {
            display: false
        },
        legendCallback: function (chart) {
            var text = [];
            text.push('<ul class="0-legend">');
            var ds = chart.data.datasets[0];
            var sum = ds.data.reduce(function add(a, b) { return a + b; }, 0);
            for (var i = 0; i < ds.data.length; i++) {
                text.push('<li>');
                var perc = Math.round(100 * ds.data[i] / sum, 0);
                text.push('<span style="background-color:' + ds.backgroundColor[i] + '">' + '</span>' + chart.data.labels[i] + ' (' + ds.data[i] + ') (' + perc + '%)');
                text.push('</li>');
            }
            text.push('</ul>');
            return text.join("");
        },

        plugins: {
            title: {
                display: true,                  
                text: 'Names',
                color: titleColor,
                padding: titlePadding,
                font: {
                    family: fontFamily,
                    size: fontSize,
                    style: fontStyle
                }
            }
        }
    }
})

var myLegendContainer = document.getElementById("legend1");
myLegendContainer.innerHTML = mychart1.generateLegend();
```

**and the html:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">
            <div>
                <canvas class="doughnutChart" id="displayVals"></canvas>
            </div>
            <div id="legend1">test</div>
        </div>
</div>
```

I can get the word 'test' to display in the , but nothing more...

Any ideas..?

Answer (score 1):

The legends namespace has been changed in V3, it is now configured in the `plugins` section, where you also configured the title.

To achieve an external legend you will need to use a custom plugin which you also need to configure in the plugins section.

You can copy paste the plugin from this official example: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/samples/legend/html.html

The only things you need to configure are:

- for the internal legend plugin you need to disable it
- for the custom legend plugin you need to provide it with the ID of the div it needs to target to generate the legend in.

Comment: Thanks. I did try in the past but now I tried again. I used the exact code in the link you sent, but it didn't work either.. there isn't an HTML example of how exactly to syntax the <div> for this legend-container, but I tried several ways and none worked... the div is empty it doesn't show anything. When you mean 'disable' the legend, do you mean `legend: {display: false,},` ?

Comment: Yes, and with an empty div it should work fine, did you provide the ID of that empty div to the inline plugin as described in the sample?

Comment: Yep, I have `plugins: {htmlLegend: {// ID of the container to put the legend in                    containerID: 'legend-container', },` and I have `<div id="legend-container"></div>`

Comment: And you also added the plugin to the chart like so: `new Chart(ctx, {data: data, options: options, plugins: [customHtmlLegendPlugin]`?

Comment: Yes, I added `plugins: [htmlLegendPlugin],` and the function is `const htmlLegendPlugin ={id: 'htmlLegend',`

Comment: Well then I don't know at the moment why it's not working, I do have a working minimalistic fiddle of an html legend which you can compare to to spot where it might go wrong: https://jsfiddle.net/Leelenaleee/yzm1ftx2/1/

Comment: Thanks! If I use a predefined chart object and do `$('#legend-container').prepend(mychart1.generateLegend());` should that work? does it matter if I add somehow the 2d context of the chart..? i.e as per the link https://codepen.io/jordanwillis/pen/PpJjWK

Comment: I thought generatelegend has been removed in v3

Comment: So if I already have a chart defined, how can I use your line of `const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);` ?